# Hide category from geom_bar() chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How do I hide the category "0" of mtcars$vs in this bar chart:

[image]

I dont want the percentages of each of the two remaining bars to change, since the bar-chart I want should be based on the same calculations as the one I've got.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot( mtcars, aes(factor(vs) )) + geom_bar(aes(y= (..count../ sum(..count..) ) ))  + facet_grid(.  ~  am,)  + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()  )
```

If, possible I want the two remaining "1"-bars to be on the same facet.

Something like this is what I'm looking for (open to improvements):

[image]

Notice that the Y-axis percentage of each of the remaining bars are around 20 %, like in the first picture.
Simple solutions are preferred :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, is this what you want?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot( mtcars[ mtcars$vs==1,], aes(factor(vs) )) +
  geom_bar(aes(y= ..count../ sum(..count..) )) +
  facet_grid(.  ~  am,)  + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

[image]

**EDIT**: To remove one level but still have the percentage relative to the all figure I'd summarise the data first and then pass it to `ggplot`. Benefits:

1) Speed. `ggplot` internal functions will be probably slower then any other split-apply-combine methods. They will be 100% slower if you decide to use `data.table` (highly recommended)

2) Easy of use. Manipulating the data before allow you to reshape and transform the data with much more tool then pushing all the row data into `ggplot`

So,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(plyr)

df1 <- ddply(mtcars, .(am, vs), summarise,
             percentage = length(vs[vs==1])/nrow(mtcars)) # percentages calculated
#respected the whole table. nrow(mtcars) can be changed with a subset of it in case
#of NAs not to be used taken into account for example.

> df1
  am vs percentage
1  0  0    0.00000
2  0  1    0.21875
3  1  0    0.00000
4  1  1    0.21875

ggplot( df1[ df1$vs==1, ], aes(factor(vs), percentage )) +
  geom_bar(sta="identity") +
  facet_grid(.  ~  am,)  + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())


df2 <- ddply(mtcars, .(am, vs), summarise,
             percentage = length(vs))
```

[image]

In case you need something slightly different, like percentages calculated inside each `am` level, then:

```
df2 <- ddply(mtcars, .(am, vs), summarise,
             percentage = length(vs))

df2$tot <- ave(df2$percentage, df2$am, FUN=sum)
df2$percentage <- df2$percentage / df2$tot
df2$tot <- NULL

> df2
  am vs percentage
1  0  0  0.6315789
2  0  1  0.3684211
3  1  0  0.4615385
4  1  1  0.5384615

ggplot( df2[ df2$vs==1, ], aes(factor(vs), percentage )) +
  geom_bar(sta="identity") +
  facet_grid(.  ~  am,)  + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

[image]

Comment: No. Sorry if the question was unclear. Each bar should be around 20 %, like in the first picture. What i want is a bar-chart with two bars where the first bar shows the probability of vs=1 among am=0, and the second bar show the probability of vs=1 among am=1. Basically I want what I've got in the first picture, but with bar #1 and bar #3 removed (while the percentages stay the same). Hope it's more clear now :)

Comment: Ok got it... you want just to hide those columns. I'm writing with the phone now. I'll update as soon I get closevto a pc ;-)

Comment: "Hide" is the word I should have used :)  I will change the title of the question. Thanks.

Comment: @RasmusLarsen, please add any (relevant) additional information that you have given in the comments also to your question. It will make it much easier to get the whole picture of your question. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. Good point about doing the calculations before feeding them to ggplot2.