# Hide category from bar chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, na

I've got a bar plot using ggplot2 that is plotting percentage of a particular thing for different age categories. How do I remove the large unnecessary column of NA value without changing the percentages? I do not want to remove the NA values from the data because it is important to see the percentage of the entire population data.

The same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893212/hide-category-from-geom-bar-chart-in-ggplot2) but no one has answered it.

Here is the code I am using:

```r
df_final %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x, y = ..prop.., group = 1), stat = "count") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  xlab("age.category") + 
  ylab("Percentage") + 
  theme_classic()
```

The output of the code. I need the giant NA column removed without disturbing the percentages.

[image: plot]

Tried using something with gtable to remove parts of the plot, but to no avail. I don't want a solution like that, I need a simple elegant solution.

Comment: Seems you need to filter out `NA` from your _data_ before sending it to `ggplot()`. Since you're already using dplyr, I suspect `filter(df_final, !is.na(x))` could work, not sure without data.

Comment: Can you share some data (ideally using `dput()`) so that others can recreate your plot?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to compute the counts and props including the `NA`s outside  of ggplot(), then filter for non-`NA`s before plotting.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(123)

df_final <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c(LETTERS[1:5], NA), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

df_final |>
  count(x) |>
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) |>
  filter(!is.na(x)) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = x, y = prop)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  xlab("age.category") +
  ylab("Percentage") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: This works. Could you please also suggest how I can display the percentage of each bar on top of it?

Comment: Try `+ geom_text(aes(x = x, y = prop, label = scales::percent(prop)), vjust = 0, nudge_y = .005)`